# Drupal 7 create and send mailchimp campaign programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, mailchimp

How to create and send mailchimp campaign programmatically in drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function kf_mailchimp_create_campaign() {
  if (!isset($_GET['cron_key']) || ($_GET['cron_key'] != 'kQ7kOy4uRgPJd1FX1QQAERPeSYuPjp1qBW65goYcbDQ')) {
    watchdog('kf_mailchimp', 'Invalid cron key !cron_key has been used to create campaign.', array('!cron_key' => $_GET['cron_key']));
    drupal_exit();
  }

  $data['site_url'] = url('<front>', array('absolute' => TRUE));
  $data['site_logo'] = theme_image(array(
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'knackforge') . '/logo.png',
    'alt' => 'KnackForge',
    'attributes' => array('border' => 0),
  ));

  $options = array(
    'list_id' =>  $mc_list_id, // Change this to match list id from mailchimp.com.
    'from_email' => variable_get('site_mail'),
    'from_name' => 'KnackForge',
    'to_email' => variable_get('site_name')
  );

  $type = 'regular';
  $q = mailchimp_get_api_object(); // Make sure a list has been created in your drupal site.

  $results = views_get_view_result('deal_mailchimp', 'page');
  // Check to prevent sending empty newsletter
  if (empty($results)) {
    watchdog('kf_mailchimp', 'No active deals to send for today');
    drupal_exit();
  }

  $data['deals'] = views_embed_view('deal_mailchimp', 'page');

  $content = array(
    'html' => theme('kf_mailchimp', $data),
  );

  $options['subject'] = t('Newsletter');
  $options['title'] = $options['subject'] . ' - ' . date('r');
  $options['tracking'] = array(
    'opens' => TRUE,
    'html_clicks' => TRUE,
    'text_clicks' => TRUE
  );

  $options['authenticate'] = false;
  $options['analytics'] = array('google'=>'atphga');

  $cid = $q->campaignCreate($type, $options, $content);

  watchdog('kf_mailchimp', 'Created campaign');

  $result = $q->campaignSendNow($cid);

  watchdog('kf_mailchimp', 'campaignSendNow() response !result', array('!result' => '<pre>' . print_r($result, 1) . '</pre>'));
```

Comment: Some comments and an explanation would be really good here to provide context.